# python, list, array, all rows automatically get updated

Tags: python, list

```
a = [[0, 0, 0]] * 3
print(a)
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
a[1][0] = 99
print(a)
[[99, 0, 0], [99, 0, 0], [99, 0, 0]]
```

here when I am trying to update `a[1][0]` every row automatically get updated how to overcome this

Comment: don't do this because lists are mutable. Do `[[0,0,0] for _ in range(3)]`

Comment: Thank you very much - Jean-François Fabre